A simple NMOS circuit simulation. Is there a way I can use KCL to find Id instead of doing Id equation?
I know the traditional way to solve this, you find Vgs then you try to find Id.
But for this circuit, we already can figure out the current flowing through the 2K and 3K by doing KVL(assuming I1). Is there any way I can figure out the other current(shown as -182uA) by doing another method? either finding the combined resistance than the current?


What do you mean "you find Vgs"? Vgs is a continuous function of current.
